# Break <option> items in loop

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am trying to loop 100 values from an API into a dropdown list. When the function runs the page loads all 100 values but inserts them into the list on 1 line, rather than on 100 separate lines. I have tried adding a break tag to the loop but that didn't work. 
How do you separate each item onto its own line?

```js
// GET STATION NAMES AND PUT THEM INTO DROPDOWN LIST
function addressList() {
    // var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=Dublin&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxx');
    // xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    //          var items = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                var items = [{"address":"Smithfield North"},{"address":"Parnell Square North"},{"address":"Pearse Street"},{"address":"Excise Walk"},{"address":"Fitzwilliam Square West"},{"address":"St. James Hospital (Central)"},{"address":"Hanover Quay"},{"address":"Oliver Bond Street"},{"address":"Collins Barracks Museum"},{"address":"Brookfield Road"},{"address":"Clonmel Street"},{"address":"Mount Street Lower"},{"address":"Christchurch Place"},{"address":"Grantham Street"},{"address":"York Street East"},{"address":"Portobello Road"},{"address":"Parnell Street"},{"address":"Frederick Street South"},{"address":"Fownes Street Upper"},{"address":"Clarendon Row"},{"address":"Custom House"},{"address":"Benson Street"},{"address":"Fenian Street"},{"address":"South Dock Road"},{"address":"The Point"},{"address":"Lime Street"},{"address":"Kilmainham Gaol"},{"address":"Guild Street"},{"address":"Herbert Place"},{"address":"Western Way"},{"address":"Newman House"},{"address":"King Street North"},{"address":"Herbert Street"},{"address":"Earlsfort Terrace"},{"address":"Golden Lane"},{"address":"Deverell Place"},{"address":"John Street West"},{"address":"City Quay"},{"address":"Exchequer Street"},{"address":"Hatch Street"},{"address":"Charlemont Street"},{"address":"Hardwicke Place"},{"address":"Wolfe Tone Street"},{"address":"Francis Street"},{"address":"Greek Street"},{"address":"High Street"},{"address":"North Circular Road"},{"address":"Talbot Street"},{"address":"Sir Patrick's Dun"},{"address":"New Central Bank"},{"address":"Georges Quay"},{"address":"Mount Brown"},{"address":"Royal Hospital"},{"address":"Heuston Station (Central)"},{"address":"Townsend Street"},{"address":"Portobello Harbour"},{"address":"Custom House Quay"},{"address":"Molesworth Street"},{"address":"Kilmainham Lane"},{"address":"Market Street South"},{"address":"Kevin Street"},{"address":"Eccles Street East"},{"address":"Grand Canal Dock"},{"address":"Merrion Square East"},{"address":"York Street West"},{"address":"St. Stephen's Green South"},{"address":"Denmark Street Great"},{"address":"Heuston Station (Car Park)"},{"address":"St. Stephen's Green East"},{"address":"Eccles Street"},{"address":"Mater Hospital"},{"address":"Blessington Street"},{"address":"Merrion Square West"},{"address":"Convention Centre"},{"address":"Hardwicke Street"},{"address":"Smithfield"},{"address":"Dame Street"},{"address":"Sandwith Street"},{"address":"Princes Street / O'Connell Street"},{"address":"Grattan Street"},{"address":"St James Hospital (Luas)"},{"address":"Bolton Street"},{"address":"Strand Street Great"},{"address":"Barrow Street"},{"address":"Mountjoy Square West"},{"address":"Wilton Terrace"},{"address":"Leinster Street South"},{"address":"James Street"},{"address":"Parkgate Street"},{"address":"Heuston Bridge (South)"},{"address":"Cathal Brugha Street"},{"address":"Rothe Abbey"},{"address":"Upper Sherrard Street"},{"address":"Fitzwilliam Square East"},{"address":"Harcourt Terrace"},{"address":"Jervis Street"},{"address":"Ormond Quay Upper"},{"address":"Emmet Road"},{"address":"Heuston Bridge (North)"},{"address":"Blackhall Place"}];
                var output = '<select>'
                for (var i in items) {
                    output += '<option>' + items[i].address + '</option>  <br>'
                }
                output += '</select>'
                document.getElementById("replaceOption").innerHTML = output
    //      }
    // }
    // xhr.send();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="stations.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="addressList()">
    <div>
        <div id="addressDropdown">
            <form>
                <select>
                    <option id="addressList" value="select station" selected="selected">Select Station..</option>
                    <option id="replaceOption">0</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Go" id="sumbit" href="#">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should never use `innerHTML` to add untrusted data to your DOM tree. What if your `item[i].address` contains a `script` tag?

Comment: This said, your question is IMO not relevant to others. It's simply a bug in how you put together your string. You should figure this out by yourself or ask a colleague, but not post it as a general question on stack overflow.

Comment: And don't expose your API keys! I had to edit the third answer now to hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append your options to the `select` element it's self. The reason why it's all on one line is because you're adding the new options **inside** an existing option rather than appending them **after** the existing option.

```js
// GET STATION NAMES AND PUT THEM INTO DROPDOWN LIST
function addressList() {
    var items = [{"address":"Smithfield North"},{"address":"Parnell Square North"},{"address":"Pearse Street"},{"address":"Excise Walk"},{"address":"Fitzwilliam Square West"},{"address":"St. James Hospital (Central)"},{"address":"Hanover Quay"},{"address":"Oliver Bond Street"},{"address":"Collins Barracks Museum"},{"address":"Brookfield Road"},{"address":"Clonmel Street"},{"address":"Mount Street Lower"},{"address":"Christchurch Place"},{"address":"Grantham Street"},{"address":"York Street East"},{"address":"Portobello Road"},{"address":"Parnell Street"},{"address":"Frederick Street South"},{"address":"Fownes Street Upper"},{"address":"Clarendon Row"},{"address":"Custom House"},{"address":"Benson Street"},{"address":"Fenian Street"},{"address":"South Dock Road"},{"address":"The Point"},{"address":"Lime Street"},{"address":"Kilmainham Gaol"},{"address":"Guild Street"},{"address":"Herbert Place"},{"address":"Western Way"},{"address":"Newman House"},{"address":"King Street North"},{"address":"Herbert Street"},{"address":"Earlsfort Terrace"},{"address":"Golden Lane"},{"address":"Deverell Place"},{"address":"John Street West"},{"address":"City Quay"},{"address":"Exchequer Street"},{"address":"Hatch Street"},{"address":"Charlemont Street"},{"address":"Hardwicke Place"},{"address":"Wolfe Tone Street"},{"address":"Francis Street"},{"address":"Greek Street"},{"address":"High Street"},{"address":"North Circular Road"},{"address":"Talbot Street"},{"address":"Sir Patrick's Dun"},{"address":"New Central Bank"},{"address":"Georges Quay"},{"address":"Mount Brown"},{"address":"Royal Hospital"},{"address":"Heuston Station (Central)"},{"address":"Townsend Street"},{"address":"Portobello Harbour"},{"address":"Custom House Quay"},{"address":"Molesworth Street"},{"address":"Kilmainham Lane"},{"address":"Market Street South"},{"address":"Kevin Street"},{"address":"Eccles Street East"},{"address":"Grand Canal Dock"},{"address":"Merrion Square East"},{"address":"York Street West"},{"address":"St. Stephen's Green South"},{"address":"Denmark Street Great"},{"address":"Heuston Station (Car Park)"},{"address":"St. Stephen's Green East"},{"address":"Eccles Street"},{"address":"Mater Hospital"},{"address":"Blessington Street"},{"address":"Merrion Square West"},{"address":"Convention Centre"},{"address":"Hardwicke Street"},{"address":"Smithfield"},{"address":"Dame Street"},{"address":"Sandwith Street"},{"address":"Princes Street / O'Connell Street"},{"address":"Grattan Street"},{"address":"St James Hospital (Luas)"},{"address":"Bolton Street"},{"address":"Strand Street Great"},{"address":"Barrow Street"},{"address":"Mountjoy Square West"},{"address":"Wilton Terrace"},{"address":"Leinster Street South"},{"address":"James Street"},{"address":"Parkgate Street"},{"address":"Heuston Bridge (South)"},{"address":"Cathal Brugha Street"},{"address":"Rothe Abbey"},{"address":"Upper Sherrard Street"},{"address":"Fitzwilliam Square East"},{"address":"Harcourt Terrace"},{"address":"Jervis Street"},{"address":"Ormond Quay Upper"},{"address":"Emmet Road"},{"address":"Heuston Bridge (North)"},{"address":"Blackhall Place"}];
    for (var i in items) {
        document.getElementById("mySelect").innerHTML += '<option>' + items[i].address + '</option>';
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="stations.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="addressList()">
    <div>
        <div id="addressDropdown">
            <form>
                <select id="mySelect">
                    <option id="addressList" value="select station" selected="selected">Select Station..</option>
                    <option id="replaceOption">0</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Go" id="sumbit" href="#">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah I understand! So i was just editing what I had just made. Thanks a lot for your help :)!

Comment: Np. You can even remove the `var output;` now too

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  let selectEl = document.getElementById('select-el');
  
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (res) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      let items = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(items);
      items.forEach(function (item) {
        let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = item.name;
        option.innerText = item.address;
        
        selectEl.appendChild(option);
      });
    }
  }
  
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=Dublin&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxx');
  xhr.send();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="stations.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div id="addressDropdown">
      <form>
        <select id="select-el"></select>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" id="sumbit" href="#" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're inserting an extra `<select>` into the existing select. Here's what your output HTML looks like:

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option id="addressList" ...</option>
    <option id="replaceOption">
      <select>
        <option>Smithfield North</option>
        ...
```

What you want to do instead is to append the options to the select box directly, rather than replacing the existing one. Note that the select box has an ID now instead of the option box. Here's the code that you need:

```js
//GET STATION NAMES AND PUT THEM INTO DROPDOWN LIST
function addressList() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=Dublin&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxx');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var items = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            
            // get the select box by id
            var addressList = document.getElementById("addressList")

            // loop through all of the items and add an option to the list
            for (var i in items) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = items[i].address;
                option.value = i
                addressList.add(option)
            }

        }
    }
    xhr.send();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="stations.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body onload="addressList()">
        <div>
            <div id="addressDropdown">
                <form>
                    <select id="addressList">
                        <option value="select station" selected="selected">Select Station..</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="sumbit" href="#">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```